# Single Sign On with JMeter (SAMLResponse not getting Value)

Tags: jmeter, single-sign-on

I have a JMeter (v 5.4.1 ) script that login's to an SSO Service, using the following steps which are a result of using BlazeMeter Recorder.

1. GET on https://stage-aa.example.com/user/login
2. GET on https://stage-aa.example.com/saml_login
   use this to declare SAMLRequest and SAMLResponse, Regular Expression Extractors

   - SAMLRequest : Regex: `SAMLRequest=(.*)RelayState=(.*)`
3. POST on https://sso.example.com/idp/EFUUU/resumeSAML20/idp/SSO.ping
   This sample uses parameters:

   - username: user_1
   - password: pass_1

The parameters are named as:
pf.username
pf.pass

4. POST on https://stage-aa.example.com/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-acs.php/default-sp
   with Parameter:

   - RelayState: https://stage-aa.example.com/saml_login
   - SAMLResponse: PHN8730Kkascnn...uyituNN (AlphaNumeric String )

with the Parameters:

- RelayState: https://stage-aa.example.com/saml_login
- SAMLResponse : Long String, which i am trying to Dynamically replace using ${SAMLResponse}

SAMLResponse is not getting value for the Regex Extractor !!!!!!!!, used SAMLResponse=(.*)

5. GET on https://stage-aa.example.com/admin/content
   This gets error: 403 Forbidden
   Since the user is not logged in, using SSO

Now, without having all results as rendered HTML, I am not sure, how I can get name/value for web elements
to be able to create a regex, which can be used in correlation

I added Debug Sampler, and I am getting values for SAMLRequest but not for SAMLResponse.

here is how SAMLResponse is exhibited in the browser:

```
 RelayState=https%3A%2F%2Fstage-aa.example.com%2Fsaml_login&SAMLResponse=PHNhbWxwOlJlc3B....
```

here is the Regex Extractor for SAMLResponse
[image]

Adding the complete JMeter Test plan ( jmx file ) had to obfuscate the URLs, but this will give you a pretty good idea. I can add the results of the execution if needed.
[jmx file gist](https://gist.github.com/kamal2222ahmed/e6a99f635e8e17cc48f2f38ac30bbff9)

Also, getting error in step 5, in the View Results Tree ( Response Body )

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  DOMDocument::loadXML(): Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found in Entity, line: 1 in <b>/var/www/vendor/simplesamlphp/saml2/src/SAML2/HTTPPost.php</b> on line <b>79</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/vendor/simplesamlphp/saml2/src/SAML2/HTTPPost.php:79) in <b>/var/www/vendor/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp/modules/redirecterrors/lib/RedirectErrors.php</b> on line <b>18</b><br />
```

here is a screenshot of SAMLResponse as Payload
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately we cannot help you with your regular expression without seeing the response data (at least partial) and your Regular Expression Extractor configuration. If you cannot come up with a good regular expression you can consider switching to

Particular your SAML implementation might be different, however my expectation is that `SAMLResponse` comes in a [hidden input field](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_hidden.asp) so it makes more sense to consider switching to [CSS Selector Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS_Selector_Extractor) configured like:

[image]

You may also find [How to Load Test SAML SSO Secured Websites with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-saml-sso-secured-websites) article useful.

Comment: Added Response Data and Regex Extractor for SAMLResponse in the question. Thanks

Comment: It doesn't tell the full story still so I can only come up with a "blind shot": change "Field to check" to `URL` and regular expression to `SAMLResponse=(.*)`

Comment: Apologize for the lack of data, just posted the complete JMX file. Still not getting the value of SAMLResponse, with the Regex you suggested.

Comment: Here is the link to the jmx file https://gist.github.com/kamal2222ahmed/e6a99f635e8e17cc48f2f38ac30bbff9